# Repopulate Listbox Using a Collectionviewsource

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, listbox

My first question!  I'm moderately familiar with vb but am a n00b with wpf.

I have a form with a listbox and a button.  I populate the listbox from a dataset connected to an Access database.  The table I am working with is named Entries and has just two columns, EntryID and Entry.  When I click on the button, a new entry is added to the database but the listbox is not repopulated.

I have read every answer for this search: "listbox collectionviewsource repopulate" but none seem to address my specific problem.

I set up my Resources as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsEntries"
           Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestDataSet}, Path=Entries}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Entry" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

I set up the listbox as follows:

```
<ListBox Name="lstEntries"
    DataContext="{StaticResource cvsStandardEntries}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Entry" />
```

My code behind for the click event is:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
Dim taEntries As TestDataSetTableAdapters.EntriesTableAdapter = New TestDataSetTableAdapters.EntriesTableAdapter
taEntries.Insert(NewEntryID, NewEntry)
```

The database is properly updated but the listbox is not.  Based on my understanding of binding, it should be.  Am I doing something wrong in my overall approach or have I missed something in the listbox and/or button code.

I know I can add this code to the button:

```
With taEntries
    .ClearBeforeFill = True
    .FillByCategory(Entry,  EntryID)
End With
```

I can force the listbox to update but that seems to violate my understanding of Binding and a bit of brute force.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (FirstQuestionReview) well done question, hope you get answers :) (You might want to edit the title to include camelcase)

Answer (score 0):

First, *Access*?  sad face...

Second, your DataContext use there is a bit odd.  Try this:

```
<ListBox Name="lstEntries"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsStandardEntries}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Entry" />
```

Third, TestDataSet isn't *observable*, so changes made to your database won't be automatically populated back to WPF.  Ideally, you should abstract your data layer away -in this case, since you're displaying lists of items in the UI that *might change on the fly*, you should be using something like `ObservableCollection`.

That said, if you don't want to go to that effort, you could refresh your collection view manually:

Dim collectionView As ICollectionView = TryCast(lstEntries.ItemsSource, ICollectionView)
collectionView.Refresh()